# getPixelFromCoordinate returning null

Tags: javascript, mapquest

In my app I added a mapquest layer with open layers 3, drawed points and lines...

Now i need to know the pixel coordinates from a long/lat point in the map (visible area) using

```
map.getPixelFromCoordinate(coordinate).
```

this function always returns `null` (testing):

```
center = map.getView().getCenter();
px = map.getPixelFromCoordinate(center);
alert(JSON.stringify(px));
```

What i'm doing wrong or what i didn't understand properly?

Answer (score 4):

I found this answer:

> I'd be careful with this. You might get wrong results, e.g. when the map does not have the final layout yet. It is better to wait with the first coordinate to pixel conversion until the map is rendered. You do not need a timeout for this, we have the 'postrender' event on ol.Map. So in your initialisation code, you could do something like this:

```
map.once('postrender', function() {
  // safe to call map.getPixelFromCoordinate from now on
});
```

Source: [github.com/openlayers/ol3/issues/5456](https://github.com/openlayers/ol3/issues/5456#issuecomment-225125384)

I hope this helps.